# How to execute the function after change page in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem.

```
.controller('A_Ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.getdata = function(){
       console.log("ok");
    }
})
```

I want to execute the function `$scope.getdata()` when view change by this view each time.

But this function is executed only once when change view by this view at first time.

My suggestion is possible in angularjs?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? What is changing the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to call the function, add the following sentence:

```
$scope.getdata();
```

Another solution: wrap it in a $rootScope and use a **$location** 
if you
want more control and based on the url you can
call getdata() or not.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.run(function($rootScope, $location) { 

   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
     $rootScope.getdata();
   });

})

.controller('A_Ctrl', function($rootScope){

   $rootScope.getdata = function(){
     console.log("ok");
   };
   $rootScope.getdata(); //----- missed line

});
```

But I recommend the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function self-executing.

```
($scope.getdata = function(){
   console.log("ok");
})();
```